# Selenium ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I m new in Selenium.

I want to execute  Ui test in visual studio  with  Selenium.
Our application  has hidden  value so I cant test it.
I read a lot of article  in here,  but i cant  understand.

I hope someone solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>

Comment: <a href="ChangePassword.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>Change Password<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

Comment: what you expect to get? can you write the code you already tried to get it

Comment: hello,  ı want to write  test case about  it,  but it has hidden value, ı try, xpad, class, , but, ıt cant run. thank you

Comment: IWebElement aria = webdriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="navbar"]/ul/li[2]/a/span[2]"));
            aria.Click();  this is not execute, vs send to massege not invisible element

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant HTML and the code you have tried with the results so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a test case to make sure that the element is hidden, then please use the below code:

```
WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='navbar']/ul/li[2]"));
if(!element.isDisplayed()) {
    console.log("Element is existing but invisible");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, your  helping  :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
webdriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='navbar']/ul/li[2]")).Click();
```

**option 2:**

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        IWebElement menuHoverLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='navbar']/ul/li[2]"));
        actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink);
        actions.Click();
        actions.Perform();
```

Comment: if not try to change the xpath to "//*[@id='navbar']/ul/li[2]/a"

Answer (score 0):

in xpath append @hidden=true
//class[contains(@id,"") and @hidden="true" ]